# Is my interpretation correct for the term "Otherwise" in [dcl.enum]/5 (5.3) below?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[dcl.enum]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#5):

> 5. Each enumeration defines a type that is different from all other types. Each enumeration also has an *underlying type*. The underlying
>      type can be explicitly specified using an *enum-base*. For a scoped
>      enumeration type, the underlying type is `int` if it is not explicitly
>      specified. In both of these cases, the underlying type is said to be
>      *fixed*. Following the closing brace of an *enum-specifier*, each enumerator has the type of its enumeration. If the underlying type is
>      fixed, the type of each enumerator prior to the closing brace is the
>      underlying type and the *constant-expression* in the
>      *enumerator-definition* shall be a converted constant expression of the underlying type. If the underlying type is not fixed, the type of
>      each enumerator prior to the closing brace is determined as follows:
>
>    - If an initializer is specified for an enumerator, the *constant-expression* shall be an integral constant expression. If the expression has unscoped enumeration type, the enumerator has the
>        underlying type of that enumeration type, otherwise it has the same
>        type as the expression.
>    - If no initializer is specified for the first enumerator, its type is an unspecified signed integral type.
>    - **Otherwise** the type of the enumerator is the same as that of the preceding enumerator unless the incremented value is not
>        representable in that type, in which case the type is an unspecified
>        integral type sufficient to contain the incremented value. If no such
>        type exists, the program is ill-formed.

My interpretation for the term Otherwise above is that it's equivalent to: "**If an initializer is not specified for an enumerator and if this enumerator is not the first in the enumeration**, then the type of the enumerator is the same as that of the preceding enumerator ...".

Comment: "otherwise" is not a term; is a common English word, whose meaning doesn't really require interpretation. In this context, it means "if none of the prior conditions hold valid", or more generally "if no other conditions apply".

Comment: Yes, but that is just English semantics and comprehension, so perhaps off-topic?  More succinctly put (and this easier to follow):  "If it has no initialiser and is not the first..."

Comment: @NicolBolas I gather from this that if the enumerator is the second in its enumeration and the first enumerator is not initialized, then the type of this second enumerator is also an unspecified signed integral type. Is this correct?